# What is error 788369013 on google play developer console?

Tags: android, google-play

When I select my app on google play console, it display popup "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (788369013)"

I can't update my app description in Store Listing (When click link it doesn't redirect to store listing)

I can't upload my app to new version

Answer (score 0):

A quick search yielded this ([Android - Managed Google Play Console IAP An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (1200001)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190839/android-managed-google-play-console-iap-an-unexpected-error-occurred-please-t)) which indicates that Google Payments needs to be enabled on your account.

There's a link within that previous question to an earlier post where the problem was resolved.

Comment: It doesn't work.
I try to clear cache on my browser and sign up merchant account but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Hmm. Sorry for spam, but what about error 2900000 ?